# How to get only a Particular field from an object array in a text file

Tags: php, arrays, api, file-get-contents

I am trying to get only the `you are doing that too much. try again in 1 minute` field from the text file using file_get _contents. please anyone solve this.

```
{
    "jquery": [
        [
            0,
            1,
            "call",
            [
                "body"
            ]
        ],
        [
            1,
            2,
            "attr",
            "find"
        ],
        [
            2,
            3,
            "call",
            [
                ".status"
            ]
        ],
        [
            3,
            4,
            "attr",
            "hide"
        ],
        [
            4,
            5,
            "call",
            []
        ],
        [
            5,
            6,
            "attr",
            "html"
        ],
        [
            6,
            7,
            "call",
            [
                ""
            ]
        ],
        [
            7,
            8,
            "attr",
            "end"
        ],
        [
            8,
            9,
            "call",
            []
        ],
        [
            1,
            10,
            "attr",
            "find"
        ],
        [
            10,
            11,
            "call",
            [
                ".error.RATELIMIT.field-ratelimit"
            ]
        ],
        [
            11,
            12,
            "attr",
            "show"
        ],
        [
            12,
            13,
            "call",
            []
        ],
        [
            13,
            14,
            "attr",
            "text"
        ],
        [
            14,
            15,
            "call",
            [
                "you are doing that too much. try again in 1 minute."
            ]
        ],
        [
            15,
            16,
            "attr",
            "end"
        ],
        [
            16,
            17,
            "call",
            []
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Did you try `json_decode`?

Comment: What happened when you did that?

Comment: You would be better off trying it yourself and then posting when you get stuck. This isn't really the place to get others to write code for you.

Comment: i am getting this error "Uninitialized string offset

Comment: Can you post some code? The message "Uninitialized string offset" is when you are accessing the characters of a string as an array but are using an index that is outside the length of the string.

Comment: i am using this code to get that field "echo $arr->jquery->{'14'}->{'3'}->{'0'};" but getting error and @dk80 please dont be rude i am new to php and stackoverflow

Comment: In the future @newman please include the relevant PHP code so users know what has been tried and what has failed for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `json_decode()`ass suggested in the comments.

If converted into associative arrays. [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
<?php

//input your json here
$json = '*** Your json ***'; 

//Decodes a JSON string, When TRUE, it will be converted into associative arrays. 
$array = json_decode($json, true);

//uncomment the next to line sif you want to echo the array
//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($array);

$text = $array['jquery'][14][3][0];
echo $text;

?>
```

Or if not converted into associative arrays

```
<?php

//input your json here
$json = '*** Your json ***'; 

//Decodes a JSON string. 
$array = json_decode($json);

//uncomment the next to line sif you want to echo the array
//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($array);

$text = $array->jquery[14][3][0];
echo $text;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You nearly had it. When accessing an array use square brackets. So instead of:

```
$arr->jquery->{'14'}->{'3'}->{'0'};
```

...use...

```
$arr->jquery[14][3][0];
```